# What level of permissions do you need to access the Workflow Settings of a library?

Tags: 2010, workflow, document-library, permissions

I am trying to access the Workflow Settings of a document library, but I get Access Denied. I am wondering what level of permissions should I have in order to go to these settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this on SharePoint 2010 and for OOTB permission levels, it looks like you would need the `Design` permission level at a minimum to access the Workflow Settings in a list/library. You can also have the `Manage Hierarchy` permission level, but this would give you a lot more access than to just the Workflow Settings.